# Material design elevations - movement on vertical axis?

Tags: css, material-design

I've been trying to make sense of Google's material design guidelines. I'm looking at them from a web perspective rather than an app.

I've read the section on elevations over and over and can't quite work out whether the vertical axis in meant to move up on 'press'.

What I do know is that shadows get bigger - that part I've sorted, however, one of the illustrations that Google provides shows a floating action button - the pressed state seems to be vertically 6px above the unpressed state.

In all other illustrations, the objects remain inline. Does anyone have a definitive answer - should dynamic components move upwards on state change?

Comment: When a widget is pressed, the shadow moves downwards a bit, because the source of light in Material Design is placed above the screen. The widget itself stays in place.

Comment: Thanks for that.